# How do I check for a certain type of value in Firebase security rules when I am setting an object?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am creating a function that will check if the

**> resource.data.dataObj**

will have certain keys in it as well as will check if the incoming values is a bool...

the hasOnly only fails to check for the value types, giving my permission error, in this case what is the right approach to target the values at each (key:value) level.

```js
request.resource.data.dataObj.keys().hasOnly(['field1', 'field2','field3']) &&
request.resource.data.dataObj.values().hasOnly(bool) && // All field values must be boolean.
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation on this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#enforcing_field_types

Comment: There's no way to enforce the type of all fields in one go, or to loop over the fields. You will need to enumerate their names in the rules, checking the type of each in turn.